# Why are integers missing some special methods in python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.x

In python 2 or 3 the built-in classes have the special method defined explicitly. [Explicit is better than implicit](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) and all that jazz.

```
5. > 4.
# True
(5.).__ge__(4.)
# True
```

But in python 2 there are exceptions for some methods, at least in the integers.

```
5 > 4
# True
(5).__ge__(4)
# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__ge__'
# But not all of them fail!
(5).__add__(4)
# 9
```

What is the cause behind this behavior? Why was it designed this way?

I am using Python 2.7.12

Comment: In Python-2.7, the `__cmp__` is used.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__

Comment: worth to mention is that in python3 `__cmp__` has been removed so for full comp You must define comp. magic methods.

Comment: It's not that something is _missing_ in python 2, it's that some things were _added_  or _changed_ in python 3.

Comment: @bryan-oakley True, but if I am understanding correctly, floats and other classes were updated after Python 2.1 (circa 2001?) but integers never were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***[data model](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html)* has been updated** between [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) and [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x). In [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) one could use the [`__cmp__` method](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__):

> **`object.__cmp__(self, other)`**
>
> Called by comparison operations if *rich comparison* (see above) is
>   not defined. Should return a **negative integer if `self < other`**,
>   **zero if `self == other`**, a **positive integer if `self > other`**. If no `__cmp__()`, `__eq__()` or `__ne__()` operation is defined,
>   class instances are **compared by object identity** ("address"). See
>   also the description of `__hash__()` for some important notes on
>   creating hashable objects which support custom comparison operations
>   and are usable as dictionary keys. (Note: the restriction that
>   exceptions are not propagated by `__cmp__()` has been removed since
>   Python 1.5.)

(formatting added)

The *rich comparison* operators are the [`__le__`, `__ge__`, etc.](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__). So in [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) there was an **additional fallback mechanism**. This is defined for an `int`, as you can see with:

```
>>> (2).__cmp__
<method-wrapper '__cmp__' of int object at 0x13ee140>
>>> (2).__cmp__(3)
-1
```

(Python 2.7.12)

Furthermore [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) **offers a [`cmp(..)` builtin function](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#cmp)**:

> **`cmp(x, y)`**
>
> Compare the two objects `x` and `y` and return an integer according to
>   the outcome. The return value is negative if `x < y`, zero if `x == y`
>   and strictly positive if `x > y`.

(formatting added)

In [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), the **`__cmp__` has been removed** as you can read in the [*What’s New In Python 3.0*](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons):

> The `cmp()` function should be treated as gone, and **the `__cmp__()`
>   special method is no longer supported**. Use `__lt__()` for sorting,
>   `__eq__()` with `__hash__()`, and other *rich comparisons* as needed. (If you really need the `cmp()` functionality, you could use the expression
>   `(a > b) - (a < b)` as the equivalent for `cmp(a, b)`.)

(formatting added)

This mechanism is not just a wrapper around `__cmp__`: it will first look whether there are *rich comparisons* and if not fallback on `__cmp__` itself.

Comment: You are right! So for some reason the `int` class was never updated when the new methods arrived.

Comment: @durum: In Python-3.x, `int` has only a `__le__`, etc., not a `__cmp__` so it has been updated. Are you sure you run this in Python-3.x?

Comment: I was talking about  python-2x. Floats were updated in python-2x, but not integers.

Comment: @durum: well in Python-2.0 you only had `__cmp__` later (but still in Python-2.x) they added `__le__`, etc. You can indeed claim the implemented `__le__`, etc. for floats but for some reason - I don't know - sticked to `__cmp__` for `int`s, that's correct.